# Photography in sunlight

Tags: exposure

I have read in most of the sites sayin take pics in sunlight which will enhance the look, my quest is , on evening time in outdoor while posing for a picture i shrinked my eyes due to direct sunlight, keepin sun behind me didnt produce good result. i can turn myself a little but light and shadow effect is not what i want. 
Sorry if its a bad question , am a beginner and  an amateur . is there any workaround for the problem?

Comment: I'm trying to decode your question.  I believe you're asking what to do about shooting with either the model's eyes squinting from the sun, or that turning away from the sun causes too much shadow?

Comment: If you are talking about harsh noon sunlight, it's not good for most forms of photography, as it's harsh and cast strong shadows.
Soft light during sunrise and sunset (golden hours) is usually considered good for photography.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking more light can help solve a lot of photography problems but direct sunlight tend to look pretty bad.

What you should do is look for "open shade" - places that are not in direct sunlight but still get lots of light - this is the easiest solution.

If you do want to take a picture in direct sunlight you probably want the sun to be to the side or behind the model (if the sun is behind the model you have to be careful with your exposure and your background, it's very easy to accidentally overexpose the background or make the model a silhouette) and use a reflector on the other side to fill in the shadow.

You don't have to buy a reflector - anything that has a light color reflects light - a white wall, a white cars or a big white t-shirt will work just fine.